# Unresolved Reference with successful build

Tags: android, gradle

one of my projects has a problem that it can't recognize any of my libraries. and I can't write any code with 3rd party libraries I already added

[image]

but the problem is my project build and runs successfully with no error, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try

```
Build >> Clean Project
Build >> Rebuild Project
```

If problem still exists, then

```
Go to you Project >> app >> libs 
Empty that folder and then Sync your project . It will download all dependencies again.
```